# Drupal: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'created'

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am programming a PHP Script to insert content into my portal with a excel file. I'm using Drupal. But it is showing an error when I tried to do so, while inserting into taxonomies.

I think that, it produced by taxonomies.

The error  I found is:

```
    exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'created' at row 1' in /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/includes/database/database.inc:2168 Stack trace: 

#0 /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/includes/database/database.inc(2168): PDOStatement->execute(Array) 
#1 /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/includes/database/database.inc(680): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array) 
#2 /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/includes/database/mysql/query.inc(36): DatabaseConnection->query('INSERT INTO {ta...', Array, Array) 
#3 /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module(1970): InsertQuery_mysql->execute() 
#4 /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module(1903): taxonomy_build_node_index(Object(stdClass)) 
#5 [internal function]: taxonomy_node_insert(Object(stdClass)) 
#6 /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/includes/module.inc(857): call_user_func_array('taxonomy_node_i...', Array) 
#7 /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/modules/node/node.module(1185): module_invoke_all('node_insert', Object(stdClass)) 
#8 /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/scriptInsercion.php(367): node_save(Object(stdClass)) 
#9 /home/anetor5/public_html/ogobdev2/scriptInsercion.php(104): crearNodo(Array) 
#10 {main}
```

How can I solve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error explaining you that, the size of the data for the column in the table is exceeded, so that data is truncated.

generally the column **created** stores unix timestamp when it was created. Make sure you have proper data for the column in the excel file.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was a timestamp! I was sending a date and It was not so!